# Array with GetElementById doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var divs = new Array("0", "c", "tb", "cn");
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length ; i++) {
        document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.borderWidth = "medium";
    }
}
```

The IDs of the divs are all stored in that array, but I am confused why it won't put borders around the text fillers I have in place. Could it possibly be that I need to use something other than borderWidth?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Notice that a plain number is (was) an invalid `id` value.

Comment: You have to set the border style as well

Comment: from memory, borders are transparent until you assign them a colour. I'd be inclined to try ".... .style.border="solid 1px black";} .....

Comment: @Bergi No console errors and changing the ID did nothing.

Comment: @enhzflep: No, borders are black by default. But border-style is `none` until you assign something…

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.border="solid medium";
```

instead of just

```
document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.borderWidth="medium";
```

Comment: `solid medium` is not a valid value for the `border-width` property. `solid` is a value for the `border-style` property. After edits: You usually need to specify a border colour too when setting the `border` property.

Answer (score 0):

When using arrays its better not to use running index since the length is not behavior as expected.
for example:

```
var arr=[];
arr[0]="0";
arr[1000]=1000;
```

What will

```
arr.length return now? 
the answer is **1001**.
```

Now if you loop on the array using index- you will get error when trying to access arr[1].

second thing: use class instead of inline style.
your code should be written in the following way:

CSS:

```
myClass{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Script

```
var divs= new Array("0", "c", "tb", "cn");
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    var key;
    // The key will not loop over the real indexes of the array
    for (key in divs) {
        // make sure that the index we need is valid and exists.
        if (divs.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            document.getElementById(divs[key]).className += 'myClass';
        }
    }
}
```